# Calling REST APIs on multiple ports using Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, mysql, eclipse

My project uses [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/projects/spring-boot). I have two Apps. The REST APIs in my first app run on port 8080 and the REST APIs in the second app run on port 8084.

I have a lot of REST calls in the JavaScript pages of the two apps. The problem is that these calls automatically go to port 8080. How can I change the port in some rest calls in the methods in my javascript ?

My JavaScript function is :

```
function loadRest() {
    const request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            let result = parseResponse(this.status, this.responseText);
            if (result != null) {
                Rest.rests = result;
                createTable();
            }
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", Rest.baseURL + "/byCompany/" + logginedCompanyId, true);
    request.send();
}
```

The REST calls automatically call port 8080. How can I change this?

Comment: specify :8084 instead of :8080 in the `baseURL`.

Comment: its return an error ? company.js:334 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8084/rest/api/Rest/byCompany/1' from origin 'http://localhost:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Comment: OK. You need to handle the CORS on the server side,

Answer (score 2):

The port that you are using is in the `Rest.baseURL` part.

You will need to change the variable somehow in your code to use port 8084 instead of port 8080.

This might be a simple workaround for you in case you cannot find a way to change the port in the `Rest.baseURL` at your end.

```
request.open("GET", Rest.baseURL.replace(":8080",":8084") + "/byCompany/" + logginedCompanyId, true);
```

I use [.replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) to change the string ":8080" (port 8080) to ":8084" (port 8084).

Comment: its not work :( its returnes an error and the rest stay : http://localhost:8080/rest/api/Rest/byCompany/1...

Answer (score 1):

finally i solved the problem with writing   @CrossOrigin
above the method in the controller .. its work . thank you